# Scala RDD groupbykey without using groupbykey function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to get an RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] without using groupbykey. These are my tuples:

```
(Group 1, John)
(Group 2, Sam)
(Group 1, Mary)
(Group 3, Pam)
```

I need to get:

```
(Group 1, List(John, Mary)), (Group 2, List(Sam)), (Group 3, List(Pam))
```

without using groupby or groupbykeys function. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you use `Scala` data structures? Or are you supposed to use only spark APIs?

Comment: yup i can! what is the optimal way to approach this?

Comment: I thought about an answer that uses Spark APIs, and I believe that its more efficient. But if you need the Scala approach, let me know.

Comment: do you think you could share the scala approach? I want to solve this without having to rely on spark df

Comment: For sure, is it okay if it’s in plain Scala? Like no usage of spark apis

Comment: sure! it could help me think of how to approach the question better too :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use Spark APIs, you can use a windowing function over key, and try to collect values into a list:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  (Group 1, John),
  (Group 2, Sam),
  (Group 1, Mary),
  (Group 3, Pam)
).toDF("key", "value")

val keyWindow = Window.partitionBy("key")

val result = df
  .withColumn(
    "values",
    collect_list(col("value")).over(keyWindow)
  )
  .select("key", "values")
  .distinct

result.show()
// here is the result:
+-------+------------+
|    key|      values|
+-------+------------+
|Group 1|[John, Mary]|
|Group 2|       [Sam]|
|Group 3|       [Pam]|
+-------+------------+
```

You can then convert this df to rdd easily!

## Update:

---

So if you want to use plain scala, assuming the data is given as follows:

```scala
val data = Seq(
    ("Group 1", "John"),
    ("Group 2", "Sam"),
    ("Group 1", "Mary"),
    ("Group 3", "Pam")
  )
```

You need to `foldLeft` over the data, with a state of `Map[String, List[String]]` (which basically means a mapping from each key/group to values), and update the state of your iteration (the Map thing)

```scala
val result = data.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[String]]) {
  case (acc, (key, value)) => 
    acc.updatedWith(key) {
      case Some(values) => Some(value :: values)
      case None => Some(value :: Nil)
    }
}
```

Just to make things clearer, you can use `.collect` on a dataframe to collect the rows as an `Array`. And, to make an `RDD` from the resulting `Map[String, List[String]]`, you can use `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(result.toSeq)`.

Comment: is there a way to do this on the RDD itself? my data is an RDD and it cant do foldLeft

Comment: @yxx You said you wanted Scala approach with Scala Datastructures, RDD is not one of them. Anyways, Rdd methods are not much different from Dataframe methods, you can adapt the first approach for your RDD.

Comment: yup its fine. I managed to think of a solution thanks!